# Не работает выпадающий список. Ошибка “Нет элемента ViewData типа ”IEnumerable <SelectListItem>“, который имеет ключ *имя*”. C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc

Контроллер:

```
      public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Books> authors;
    using (Model1 db = new Model1())
    {
        authors = db.Books.ToList();
        SelectList author = new SelectList(db.Authors, "Id", "FirstName", db.Authors.Select(model => model.Id));
        ViewBag.AuthorId = author;
    }
    return View(authors);




}
```

Представление:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AuthorId, ViewBag.AuthorId as SelectList)
```

Модель:

```
public partial class Books
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int? Pages { get; set; }
    public int? Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Authors Authors { get; set; }


}

public partial class Authors
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Authors()
    {
        Books = new HashSet<Books>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Books> Books { get; set; }



}
```

Скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, в чем проблема. Проверял код, пишу все правильно, но при попытке создать поле с названием книги, цены, и кол-ва листов - выходит эта ошибка "Нет элемента ViewData типа "IEnumerable ", который имеет ключ имя". Уже не знаю в чем дело, и как исправить.

Пытался найти решение на форумах, создавал список по гайдам и статьям, но все равно один и тот же результат.

Причем, если использовать обычный EditorFor, и ввести Id созданного автора - всё работает. Что я делаю не так? Из-за чего возникает ошибка, и как её исправить?

Заранее, большое спасибо.

Специально для @Yaroslav:

```html
@model WebApplication3.Books @using WebApplication3.Helpers @{ ViewBag.Title = "Create"; } @ImageHelper.Image(Html, "https://www.solvusoft.com/file-extensions/images/software/200x200/267_asp-net.png", "asp") @{ string[] fields = new string[] { "Book's
Title", "Book's Price" }; }

<h3>Fields</h3>
@ListHelper.CreateList(Html, fields)




<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
  <h4>Books</h4>
  <hr /> @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)


  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AuthorId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AuthorId, ViewBag.AuthorsList as SelectList) @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AuthorId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@ @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuthorId, "", new { @class
      = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pages, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pages, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pages, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
      <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}

<div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AuthorId, ViewBag.AuthorList as List<SelectListItem>)

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AuthorId, (SelectList)ViewBag.AuthorList)

Comment: @Yaroslav Спасибо, но, к сожалению, это не работает. Всё та же ошибка. Я уже не знаю в чем проблема.

Comment: покажите все представление.

Comment: @Yaroslav К сожалению, в комментарий не вмещается такое количество символов, поэтому я добавил в заглавный пост

Comment: @Yaroslav Я не понимаю, что не так с представлением. Там все как и должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedAuthorId,
        Model.Authors.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.FirstName,
            Value = x.Id.ToString(),
            Selected = x.Id == Model.SelectedAuthorId
        })
    )
</div>


public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Books> authors;
    using (Model1 db = new Model1())
    {
        authors = db.Books.ToList();
        var author = new SomeModel {SelectedAuthorId = 1, Authors = authors};
    }
    return this.View(author);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не самая лучшая реализация но она помогает искать используя ввод

```
   <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="orgId" class="form-control-label">Authors:</label>
                            <input list="organization" class="form-control" id="orgId" name="orgId">
                            <datalist id="organization">
                                @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.organization) {
                                    <option id="@item.Id" value="@item.NameRU" />
                                }

                            </datalist>
                        </div>
```

Через ViewBag код на контроллере

```
 var authors = db.Books.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name}).toList();
    ViewBag.Authors = authors
```

Разор

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id", ViewBag.Authors as SelectList)
@Html.DropDownList("Id", new SelectList(ViewBag.Authors , "Id", "Name"))
```